# Iterating over pandas series in reversed order

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, series

How to iterate over pandas series in reversed order?

The regular iteration is:

```
for index, value in series.items():
```

How to do it in reverse, something like:

```
for index, value in reversed(series.items()):
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reverse a `Series` like below:

```
In [251]: s = pd.Series([0,1,2])
```

To reverse it:

```
In [252]: s.iloc[::-1]
Out[252]: 
2    2
1    1
0    0
```

To iterate it, you can do this:

```
In [254]: for ix, val in s.iloc[::-1].items():
     ...:     print(val)
     ...: 
2
1
0
```